# Hiding Nested Form Fields and Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm using the [nested_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) in my ruby on rails 4 application. In each nested form that is added, there are several divs with fields in them. I want to hide the content of those divs when the nested form is added. With my current jQuery function, every nested form's divs are hidden (even on forms that are filled in by the user correctly).

The HTML + JS I'm adding with each nested_form addition:

```
<%= f.fields_for :loan_securities, :wrapper => true do |loan_security| %>
<div class="div1">
    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="label col col-6 required">Serial Number</label>
            <div class="col col-6">
                <label class="input">
                    <%= loan_security.text_field :security_serial_number, :class => "security_serial_number" %>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="div2">
    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="label col col-6 required">Registration Number</label>
            <div class="col col-6">
                <label class="input">
                    <%= loan_security.text_field :security_registration_number, :class => "security_registration_number" %>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<% end %>

$(function() {
  $(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
    $(".div1").hide();
    $(".div2").hide();
  });
});
```

The above is not not working correctly. I want to only hide div1 and div2 in the nested form that was added on that event, not all of the nested forms. In the documentation they show how to use the events to access a single field:

```
$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
  // this field was just inserted into your form
  var field = event.field; 
  // it's a jQuery object already! Now you can find date input
  var dateField = field.find('.date');
  // and activate datepicker on it
  dateField.datepicker();
})
```

How would I use the above example to access both divs and hide them in the form that was added?

Comment: Can we see your html?

Comment: From past experience, when you use $(<selector>) it returns an array of elements. Try $('.div1')[0].hide() and $('.div2')[0].hide()

Comment: @Daryl Doesn't seem to work. In console I get a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined.